# Update item Firebase using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi I'm developing a web page where there is a list of items displayed in jsGrid and the user can edit each item, now I have the new object (the updated one), but I cannot figure out how to send the object to Firebase Database and update the existing one.

Of course I could delete the old one and then insert the new one but i think there is something more appropriate for this kind of task.

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

I was doing something similar with my program. I'm not sure what your data structure looks like, but mine was a parent with 6 children. You could easily update one of those children by using the .set method, and for the child you would like to update, you set the new value to be the input value or whatever value your user changes it to. Then the rest of the values you can just set them to be what they already are using the childSnapshot.val() -- you would have to do the for each function. Hope that helps. Let me know if you have any questions. 
--to clarify I used javascript for the function